# Keychain can’t find item but then can’t create item

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

Im having real trouble with the keychain on iOS.

Here is `self.keychainItemQuery`:

```
{
    kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    kSecAttrGeneric = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecMatchLimit = kSecMatchLimitOne;
    kSecReturnAttributes = kCFBooleanTrue;
}
```

When i do

```
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)self.keychainItemQuery, &attributes);
```

i get

```
status == errSecItemNotFound
```

So ok, Here is `self.keychainItemData`:

```
{
    kSecAttrAccount = "";
    kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    kSecAttrDescription = "";
    kSecAttrGeneric = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecAttrLabel = "";
    kSecValueData = <35663636 65623135 64303139 65363535>;
}
```

But when i do

```
OSStatus result = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);
```

I get

```
result == errSecDuplicateItem
```

I thought keychain items were keyed off `kSecAttrGeneric`. The query above finds the keychain item at other points in the code. I feel like im missing some detail about why this doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/28/keychain-duplicate-item-when-adding-password.html) talks about your problem.

In short, you also need to set values for keys `kSecAttrAccount` and `kSecAttrService`. `kSecClassGenericPassword` apparently determines uniqueness of a keychain entry from those two values.

You can reuse your value for `kSecAttrGeneric` in `kSecAttrService`, but each keychain entry needs a unique `kSecAttrAccount` value.

Updating your examples, `self.keychainItemQuery` becomes:

```
{
    kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    kSecAttrGeneric = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecAttrAccount = "account";               // This value should be unique for each entry you add
    kSecAttrService = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecMatchLimit = kSecMatchLimitOne;
    kSecReturnAttributes = kCFBooleanTrue;
}
```

and `self.keychainItemData` becomes:

```
{
    kSecAttrAccount = "";
    kSecClass = kSecClassGenericPassword;
    kSecAttrDescription = "";
    kSecAttrGeneric = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecAttrAccount = "account";               // This value should be unique for each entry you add
    kSecAttrService = "com.mycompany.player";
    kSecAttrLabel = "";
    kSecValueData = <35663636 65623135 64303139 65363535>;
}
```